# Can't load a new image from .xcassets file

Tags: swift, xcode, assets

I'm unable to load an image that I added to a .xcassets file today.

```
let image = UIImage(named: "slider_star")
print(image)  // nil
```

Other older images from the exact same assets file load just fine (in the exact same spot in code). I can see the image just fine in .xib files, and if I put it in a UIImage in a .xib file it appears just fine in the simulator, too.

I've tried cleaning my build folder, restarting Xcode, using different simulators, and loading it as an Image Literal (can select it from the image list, but simulator crashes when it tries to render the image). I also made sure the target membership is correct, and that the assets file is in copy bundle resources, and that the image files are indeed inside the assets file in Finder. Also all settings for the image set are the same as other working image sets.

Any idea why this is happening?

edit: More things I've tried from suggestions in the comments:

- change name from "star" -> "slider_star"
- check that the color space of all images are the same as working ones
- check that there is no extra white space at the end of slider_star.
- also tried making another new image set, and re-using some of the confirmed working images in it, but this also comes back nil. I think this probably rules out any issue with the image files themselves, at least. It's almost like xcode isn't seeing the updates to the .xcassets file, but that's strange because the updates are showing up and working fine in .xib files.

[image]

Comment: star is the same name for system image try to change name and check

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I gave that a try, but unfortunately it's still coming back nil.

Comment: attach assets ss might be helpfull

Comment: Sure, I updated with a ss.

Comment: The color space of this one vs the working ones? Check the 3 versions of them just in case?

Comment: Maybe slider_star has an extra white space at the end "slider_star "

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, I just checked. The color space of all 3 version is sRGB IEC61966-2.1, which is the same as the working ones (all images were exported from figma). Also no extra space at the end :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured this out. This is a fairly large project with multiple targets, and it seems that the code in the target I'm working in is for some reason looking at the .xcassets file from another target (I checked the other xcasset file's target membership, and it's *not* included in the target I'm working in, so I don't understand why this is happening).

I can work around this by putting my images in the other xcasset file (don't really like this), or specifying the bundle with UIImage(named:in:with:).

If anyone knows why this is happening, I'd love to fix the root issue (maybe it's not an issue, and I'm just not understanding how it's supposed to work). I'll let this sit for 24 hours before accepting this as an answer.